# Non-angular website - check results are sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

Would you please advise, how to validate non-angular website search results are displayed in sort order?

I was trying to capture all listed items in an array, and later to validate them if they are in sort order or not. however unable to push test results into an array. Please could you see following code-snippet and advise on this.

```
//element locator for all funds.
var fundingOpportunityList = element.all(by.css('#search-results-list li a article h3'));

//page object
var fundingOpportunityPage = function(){

this.checkFundingItemsSorted = function() {
        //temporary array to store results
         var temp = [];

        //check 10 funding opportunities shown in first pagination tab
        fundingOpportunityList.then(function(items) {
          //Following section working i.e. 10 items shown in each page.
          expect(items.length).toBe(10);  

        }); 

        //This section is not working, unable to save results in Array
        fundingOpportunityList.each(function(elem,index){
            //retrieve all funding opportunities and store in an array
              elem.getText().then(function (text) {
                expect(text).toMatch('junk');  //this line added for debugging
                temp.push(text);    //trying to push text into an array

            });


        }); 

        expect(temp.length).toBe(10);  //length shown as 0
        expect(temp).toEqual('hello'); 

    }
```

Following is test result output.

> 1) Test website - funding opportunity list - Check Funding list is
>   displayed in sorted order    Message:
>        Expected 0 to be 10.    Stacktrace:
>        Error: Expected 0 to be 10.
>
> 2) test website - funding opportunity list  - Check Funding list is
>   displayed in sorted order    Message:
>        Expected [  ] to equal 'hello'.    Stacktrace:
>        Error: Expected [  ] to equal 'hello'.
>    3) test website - funding opportunity list  - Check Funding list is displayed in sorted order    Message:
>        Expected '15 for 2015' to match 'junk'.
>    4) test website - funding opportunity list  - Check Funding list is displayed in sorted order    Message:
>        Expected '3Rs Prize' to match 'junk'.
>    5) test website - funding opportunity list  - Check Funding list is displayed in sorted order    Message:
>        Expected '3Rs Research Funding Scheme - Project Grants' to match 'junk'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `each()`, use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var fundingOpportunityList = element.all(by.css('#search-results-list li a article h3'));

var opportunities = fundingOpportunityList.map(function(elem) {
    return elem.getText();
});

expect(opportunities).toEqual(['hello1', 'hello2']);
```